# How to find active FTP users in the last 60 days?

Tags: redhat, sftp, users, user-accounts, login

Hi I'm not really a sysadmin, but I inherited a webserver running Red Hat 3.

I'm going to replace the server with a newer OS, but I want to find out which users are still using it.  My users don't have SSH access, only FTP.

How do I find out who has uploaded something into this server in the last 60 days?  Is there a log file that keeps track of SFTP logins?

Or is there a way to find files that were changed in the last 60 days?

Comment: What is the output of `grep sftp /etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: I'd like to know beforehand what ftp/sftp service you're running, if possible.  What you're running may help in finding out

Comment: Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find logs from the  FTP server somewhere below /var/log, this is a first step but might not be enough in case of log rotation and seldom use.

To find all files files modified in the last 60 days, you can use the `find` command:

```
find / -type f -mtime -60 -print
```

will list all files modified in the last 60 days. If you know where the files would be stored, you could restrict this list further by giving this to find, i.e.

```
find /var/ftp -type f -mtime -60 -print
```